# How to write a squence that iterate 2,-3,4,-5?

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

I want write a program that prints 100 members of sequence such as 2,-3,4,-5 using console application.

But I didn't use for loop.

Please help me.

Comment: "But I didn't use for loop." - Why not? That's the obvious approach...

Comment: If this is homework then it will make sense.

Comment: This is not my homework

Answer (score 1):

Building the sequence:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Sequence()
{
   int current = 0;
   int sign = 1;

   while(true)
   {
      current++;
      sign *= -1;
      yield return current * sign;
   }
}
```

Taking the first 100 and printing them (for example in main)

```
Sequence().Take(100).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int current;
        int sign = 1;
        int result;
        for (current = 1; current <= 100; ++current)
        {
            sign *= -1;
            result = current * sign;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: My answer is that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one as a simple function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <=100; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(AlternatingSignSequence(i).ToString() + " ");               
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int AlternatingSignSequence(int input)
    {
        return ((input % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1) * input;
    }
```